# jquery submit button doesn't work

Tags: jquery, submit

This may be too simple, but I'm not seeing why this submit button is not working - no alert from either attempt.  Total newbie here.
I'll need to add more search fields like zip, so I need to get this working,
Other eyes will help and be greatly appreciated:

```
    <html xmlns="//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml "> 
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Rent Properties</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #searchFields
    {
       background-color:silver;
       padding:6px;       
       height: 30px;
       width: 300px;
       position: fixed;
       z-index: 1;
       left: 0%;
       top: 0%;
       margin: 0px 0 0 0px;         
    }
#Properties
{
//background-color:#f0f0f0; 
//height: 60px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;  
left: 0%;
text-align: center;
top: 60px;
margin: 0px 0 0 0px;   
}   
 </style>

 </head>
        <body>
      <form id='rentProp' name="rentProp" >
       <p><br><br><br><font style="font-size:3em;z-index: 1000">&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>Loading ...</i></font><br><br></p>
        <div id='searchFields'></div>
        <div id='Properties'></div>
       </form>
    </body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var zip="";
       $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        output = "<table><tr><td>Zip: <input type='text' name='zipcd' id='zipcode'>  <input type='submit' value='Go' name='searchButton' class='button' id='searchButton' /><br></td></tr></table><BR>";
    //Get Search Zip entered on submit
    $('#searchButton').on('click', '#searchButton', function(){
        zip = document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
        zip = $('#zipcode').val();  // tried zip= one at a time and also tried this one line outside of the function
        alert(zip);  // works but zip = "" outside of this function
    });
        $('#searchFields').html(output);
   $(document).ready(function () {
        if (zip == "") { fnd = 0; }
        else { fnd = zipcode.search(zip); }
        // much more code here including more html output
   });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: check your browser console log for errors

Comment: your script is not within a script element?

Comment: `searchButton` is created dynamically so need to use event delegation or the handler should be added after the element is created

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t6t9oxb0/1/

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery is written under the  tag only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

//Get Search Zip entered on submit
$('#searchButton').on('click',function(){
    zip = document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
    alert(zip);
});
$('.searchButton').on('click', function () {
    zip = document.getElementById('zipcode').value;
    alert('zip:' + zip);
}); 

 output = "<table><tr><td>Zip: <input type='text' name='zipcd' id='zipcode'>  <input type='submit' value='Go' name='searchButton' class='button' id='searchButton' /><br></td></tr></table><BR>";
    $('#searchFields').html(output);
</script>
```

Comment: If you mean within the script tags, it is - that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to attach click handler to `#searchButton`, it doens't exist. All you have to do is to change:

`$('#searchButton').on('click', function() { ...`

To

`$('#searchFields').on('click', '#searchButton', function() { ...`

For more information, check [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: This worked  - adding the #searchButton after the click, but it lost the value of zip immediately after the function completed.
Nothing else above worked.
Console shows it just skips the click functions.
Could it be because the output is not in the form itself?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you check if this fiddle works. https://jsfiddle.net/jansav/gjkopenL

Comment: The fiddle works, but zip is defined outside of the function - how do I use that global field instead of losing the value after the function is completed?

Comment: Feel free to define zip outside of the function. But value is always obtainable by ``document.getElementById('zipcode').value`` . Also if you define zip outside of function, it will be null until you actually click button. (http://jsfiddle.net/jansav/gjkopenL/4/)

Comment: I tried 
    zip = $('#zipcode').val();
but got an undefined error immediately after.
Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Undefined means that element is not at DOM yet. I updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jansav/gjkopenL/5/

Comment: It didn't work, so I "fiddled" with it some - this is not going to give me the value of zip after the function ends.  If you'll look at the updated code in the original question, you'll see that I need it later.  
Thanks for trying though - I really hope that I can find a way to get the value of a variable on submit.  Shouldn't be this difficult -

Comment: Zip -variable gets value only after click of button, so you can't depend of its value at ``document.ready``. If you need to do something depending of value, you should check ``.on('change', ...`` or ``.on('input', ...`` -methods. Or maybe just call custom function after changing value of zip.

Comment: I can get the result with this, but I have no idea if this is going to work out in the long term with all the search buttons I will have to add:
        var url = window.location.href;
       KeysValues = url.split(/[\?&]+/);
       for (i = 0; i < KeysValues.length; i++) {
          KeyValue = KeysValues[i].split("=");
          if (KeyValue[0] == "zipcd") {
            if (zip == "") {
                zip = KeyValue[1];
            }
          }
        }